# Upload image, a badge is added

Tags: node.js, database-design

I need to create a form, the functions should be 1. upload images with it 2. a badge is added to the picture uploaded 3. the picture should be downloaded with badge on it. what code or language can i use for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use HTML for the form which will send the image to a php script, search for "tuto watermark php" ;).

PHP is the most common, but if you know more about python or nodejs for example, you can do this tool in almost all languages.

Find a language framework that processes images to help you.

Comment: Can this be done on wordpress website too? thanks for the help

Comment: @AyodejiFasesin Of course you can create this type of function on Wordpress. Either in the theme folder used (fully configurable), or by creating a page dedicated to your script that you will put anywhere in your wordpress folder with a link that takes you there.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help